# Gnuplot: Alternating colors in fenceplots

Tags: colors, gnuplot, fence-plots

I want to to plot a fenceplot with alternating fence colors. In this case I want black and grey. I used the following code:

`splot for [i=0:300:25] "fenceplot.csv" index i u 1:2:3 w lines`

The number of fences defined in my data file is dynamic and is usually between 250-350 fences.

[image: Fence]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the variable `i` changes by 25 between subsequent curves you can decide which color to use for a given line by testing whether `i` is even or odd:

```
set style line 1 linecolor "black"
set style line 2 linecolor "grey"
splot for [i=0:300:25] "fenceplot.csv" index i u 1:2:3 w lines linestyle 1+i%2
```

Slightly more robust would be

```
splot for [i=0:12] "fenceplot.csv" index i*25 u 1:2:3 w lines linestyle 1+i%2
```

because then you can also replace 25 by an even number.